# Incluir classe PHP(PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

Bom, comecei meu estudos sobre PDO recentemente, estou tentando incluir uma classe em um formulário, porém está dando o erro:

> failed to open stream:

Isso tanto se eu usar o include direto com o caminho, quanto se eu usar essa função: (Obs: Na classe MetodosPDO ela funciona).

```
  function __autoload($class) {
        $class = strtolower($class);
        // Inclui a classe que precisamos
        include_once("classes/class-{$class}.php");
    }
```

ConnectionFactory.php

```
   class ConnectionFactory{
       static function getConnection(){
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projeto_php_pdo", "root", ""); 
    return $con;
       }
    }
```

MetodosPDO.php

```
   class metodosPDO {

       function __autoload($class) {
          $class = strtolower($class);
          // Inclui a classe que precisamos
          include_once("classes/class-{$class}.php");
        }

       static function inserirCliente($nome, $sobrenome) {
          $con = ConnectionFactory::getConnection();
          $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO pessoa(nome, sobrenome) VALUES(?, ?)");
          $stmt->bindParam(1, $nome);
          $stmt->bindParam(2, $sobrenome);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->close();
          return;
         }
      }
```

pag_cadastro.php

```
    <?PHP
     // INCLUIR AQUI
    ?>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nome" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btn" />
    </form>

    <?php
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
        $verf = metodosPDO::inserirCliente($nome, $sobrenome);
    ?>
```

A estrutura de pasta está assim:

Arquivos de código-fonte: 
PDO ~> MetodosPDO.PHP / ConnectionFactory.php
formularios ~> pag_cadastro.php

Comment: Não será por o teu `__autoload` converter tudo para lowercase? E os ficheiros estarem camelCase?

Comment: Esse foi um dos erros, o outro foi o caminho do __autoload, o certo do include seria "include_once("../PDO/{$class}.php");". Obrigado pela ajuda!